# ¿Cómo se realiza una pregunta con una conjunción disyuntiva?

Tags: gramática, preguntas

Digamos que quiero preguntarle a alguien si fui yo quién lo despertó o si ya estaba despierto, ¿cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo?, se me ocurren las siguientes posibilidades:

- ¿Estabas despierto?, O te desperté...
- ¿Estabas despierto o te desperté?.
- ¿Estabas despierto? ¿o te desperté?.
- ¿Estabas despierto? o, ¿te desperté?.

Yo pienso que es la primera, aunque no estoy seguro. ¿Alguna ayuda?, ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De hecho, menos la primera todas son correctas. El equivalente en inglés sería así:

- ¿Estabas despierto? O te desperté...     *Were you awake? Or did I awake you...*

In this case it is no not correct because you're not asking, you're assuming it.

---

- ¿Estabas despierto o te desperté? *Were you awake or did I awake you?*

This is fine. One question with a conjunction

---

- ¿Estabas despierto? ¿O te desperté? *Were you awake? Or did I awake
  you?*

Fine also, there are two different questions, both of them are ok

---

- ¿Estabas despierto? O, ¿te desperté? *Were you awake? Or, did I awake you?*

Same, two questions, in this case, the conjunction is outside the question but it is equally correct

Otro detalle a tener en cuenta, detras del interrogante "?" no se pone punto (ni coma tampoco). El interrogante cuenta como un punto, por lo tanto después siempre debes poner mayúscula.

Comment: ¡Hola! Mi idioma nativo es el español, aunque muchas gracias por escribirlo en inglés, me ayuda a establecer analogías. Entiendo lo que dices, pero no me suenan muy bien las demás (aunque estoy de acuerdo con que la primera contiene una afirmación, no una pregunta). ¿Cuál de todas las demás es la que 'suena' mejor? es decir, ¿cuál es 'más' correcta?. ¡Gracias! PD: No estoy seguro que se diga *did I awoke you?* dado que el *did* ya 'carga' el pasado.

Comment: Ya, yo tampoco lo tengo muy claro en inglés... Quizá elegiría la tercera opción (¿Estabas despierto? ¿O te desperté?) como la más genérica, pero todas valdrían. También depende de cómo lo quieras decir y del contexto, aunque sean equivalentes, el decirlo de un modo u otro implica realizar unas pausas distintas en cada caso.

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta! te entiendo perfectamente, muchas gracias Héctor.

Comment: Los símbolos ! y ? llevan un punto incorporado y no hace falta poner otro, pero sí que se puede poner una coma detrás si se desea continuar la frase tras la pregunta o exclamación. Así, podríamos decir _¿Estabas despierto?, ¿o te he despertado?_ Tienes [un ejemplo en el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=interrogaci%C3%B3n): _Vamos a ver... ¡Caramba!, ¿son ya las tres?; se me ha hecho tardísimo._

Answer (score 2):

Lo correcto para lo que preguntas es la segunda (¿Esto o esto?).  Sin el punto final que agregaste, desde luego.  Esa es una sola pregunta completa con la disyunciòn que buscas.

En el tercer caso "¿Esto?  ¿o esto?", el hecho de usar dos preguntas implica retractarse **un poco** de la primera;  es decir, se  asume que la respuesta a la primera pregunta puede ser más negativa que positiva y por eso la segunda iniciada con "o". Aunque también podría tener otro impacto, como por ejemplo, mayor cortesía o consideración, al no imponer una visión.  De hecho, en este caso particular de "¿Estabas despierto? ¿o te desperté?", yo interpretaría la segunda pregunta como una disculpa de haberme despertado en el caso posible de haberlo hecho. ---- Por cierto,  no pondría la conjunción "o" con mayúscula, para darle tratamiento del mismo enunciado. De hecho, a diferencia del inglés,  en español es muy raro iniciar enunciado con una conjunción, en caso de requerir una pausa tan larga como para no querer usar coma,  optaría por puntos suspensivos. Un caso en el que iniciaría un enunciado con una conjunción sería: (después de cambiar el tema)  "¿Y qué me querías decir?" (o bien,  "Y... ¿qué me querías decir?").

En el cuarto caso,  no usamos coma después de "o" a menos de que vayamos a poner una idea parentética. Por ejemplo: Te gusta esa chica o, como decía el tío, "la muchacha".
Luego, no usaríamos la conjunción fuera del signo de interrogación a menos de que en verdad sea otra pregunta: "Hay muchas interrogantes: ¿siempre fue así? , ¿evolucionó?, ¿es una nueva raza? y/o ¿proviene de una alteración genética?". **De esta manera**, admito que este podría aplicarse como el segundo caso y ser dos preguntas, pero con otro impacto. Al separar la conjunción de la pregunta, das cabida a un espacio o silencio,  y de hecho lo representaste  erróneamente con una coma. Así, "¿Estabas despierto?  o ¿te desperté?" simula una pausa después de la "o" y de hecho, hace que la "o" sea una afirmación que rechaza totalmente y casi sin lugar a duda la primera pregunta y presenta una nueva interrogante, que puede interpretarse de diversas maneras; a mí se me ocurre como una idea inesperada, quizás podría expresarla con las palabras: "¿será a caso?". En este caso descarta completamente la idea de que estaba despierto, y podría imaginar que la segunda pregunta significa: "Ups, no me digas que te de desperté."

Comment: ¡Excelente! agradezco mucho tu respuesta (no sabía lo del punto final, muchas gracias).

Comment: Yo leo "¿Estabas despierto? o ¿te desperté?" como una enumeración de preguntas, no como una pregunta en sí. Por ejemplo, aconsejando qué preguntar: --Puedes preguntarle "¿Vamos al cine?" o "¿Te parece hacer algo esta noche?"

Answer (score 1):

Llevo un tiempo dándole vueltas a esto y aún no encuentro una respuesta clara, hay un caso curioso que como programador tengo presente en todo momento cuando me planteo este dilema... Voy a dejar mi opinión y si fallo en algo corregidme por favor. "Al fin y al cabo soy de números pero me esfuerzo por redactar lo mejor posible :)" De hecho, ya que estoy, perdonad las faltas de ortografía.

El tema es que hay dos formas de interpretar '**¿Estabas despierto o te desperté?**'.

En la primera situación es como usar un operador logico OR, se da por hecho que no tiene por qué ser cierta ninguna de las dos condiciones, es decir, puede que estés preguntando las dos a la vez esperando una respuesta de sí o no (en el caso de que se cumpla mínimo una será sí y si no se cumple ninguna será no)

En este caso a mí me parece que la forma correcta es expresarlo en una sola pregunta sin comas ya que al pronunciarlo el tono de pregunta empieza en el primer caso y acaba en el segundo, además, no se pausa.

En la segunda situación se da por hecho que una de las dos seguro que va a ser cierta y se espera como respuesta uno de los dos casos por lo tanto yo usaría una coma, ya que en este caso se pronuncia de forma pausada pero no se usan dos tonos de pregunta si no que pausas a mitad de la entonación, por lo tanto sería: **¿Estabas despierto, o te desperté?**

No creo que sea correcto usar **¿Estabas despierto?,¿O te desperté?** debido a que no se entona así la pregunta. Al menos desde mi punto de vista, para muestra prueba a leer estas preguntas exagerando tu tono de pregunta y verás como no se pronuncian igual, en la primera utilizas un tono seguido de pregunta aunque con una pausa y un final un poco menos 'melódico' cerca del final y en la segunda dos tonos, a mi me parece que lo que buscamos es mas similar a la primera. "He quitado la 'o' en la segunda para que se entienda mi punto"

**¿Estabas despierto, o te desperté?**

**¿Estabas despierto?, ¿Te desperté?**

Ahora prueba a leer esto con la entonación de la segunda, ¿no suena raro?: **¿Estabas despierto?,¿O te desperté?**

De hecho la segunda forma sería un planteamiento nuevo sin o, por lo que esperas dos respuestas de sí o no, una por cada pregunta... Como mola analizar la lengua.

No se, he respondido de forma bastante subjetiva basada en el terreno de la programación, creo que gramaticalmente no es así pero me parece que es un planteamiento coherente con nuestra forma de pronunciar que permite a su vez diferenciar ambos casos al leerlos sin necesidad de un contexto de la pregunta, en fin, me gustaría saber que opinan de este planteamiento y me corrijan si está mal. Muchas gracias :)